# PowerAutomate - Can you convert a .msg file into a .pdf with PowerAutomate?

Tags: power-automate

I've tried converting .msg files to .pdf's and I'm to the point of using 'Get Files in Folder', but I don't see a convert file Action in PowerAutomate.  is this possible in PA?

PA version: 2.14.217.21314

Thank you.

Comment: @KJ, thanks for the help.  I don't see the files until they are already .msg files.  I appreciate your time.

Comment: You can run a PowerShell script in your Flow, and in that script something similar to this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/60459504/1054225) may be an option.